# .NET Core exception in dotnet.exe console

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core application that is using a generic exception filter to handle logging to an external system. The filter looks like this:

```
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is OperationCanceledException)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_ignoreUnauthorizedExceptions && context.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return;
        }

        var requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Request-ID", requestId);
        context.Result = new ObjectResult(null) { StatusCode = 500 };

        Log.Error($"Request-ID: {requestId} Unhandled exception.", context.Exception);
    }
```

I need to explicitly set `context.Result` in order to get my custom header to be set in the response to the client. But when doing this, I no longer get the stack trace in the dotnet.exe console window.

Instead, I just get a row like this:

```
Request finished in 1219.6822ms 500
```

For local development, it would be nice to get the full stack trace in the console. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure if it would be possible, but you could try adding this: `Console.WriteLine(context.Exception.StackTrace);`

Comment: That kind of works, I get the stack trace to the console. But since the default behavior is to print it, I was hoping to be able to hook into that.